# Unable to run multiple controller tests in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm attempting to clean up an existing application by writing unit tests for some legacy code (and updating it along the way). I've rewritten a number of libraries and I've really been loving the TDD approach. However, now it's time to move on to testing some controllers, and I've run into a problem on the very first set of tests. I'm following the explanations in Jeffery Way's *Laravel Testing Decoded*.

The goal here is to test my login route: `http://my-development-server/login`. The code should work like this: first, check to see if someone is already logged in - if they are, redirect them to the dashboard (the main page in the app). Otherwise, render the login page. Pretty straight forward.

Here are the routes involved:

```
Route::get('login', array(
        'as'        => 'login',
        'uses'      => 'MyApp\Controllers\AccountController@getLogin',
    ));

Route::get('/', array(
        'as'        => 'dashboard',
        'uses'      => 'MyApp\Controllers\DashboardController@showDashboard',
        'before'    => 'acl:dashboard.view',
    ));
```

Here's the `AccountController::getLogin` method:

```
public function getLogin()
{
    // Are we logged in?
    if (\Sentry::check())
        return Redirect::route('dashboard');

    // Show the page.
    return View::make('account.login');
}
```

I'm using the `Sentry` library for user authentication.

And here's my first test:

```
class AccountControllerTest extends TestCase {

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    public function test_login_alreadyLoggedIn()
    {
        // arrange
        //
        \Sentry::shouldReceive("check")
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true);

        // act
        //
        $response = $this->call("GET", "/login");

        // assert
        //
        $this->assertRedirectedToRoute("dashboard");
    }
}
```

This test emulates the "user attempts to log in when they're already logged in" case. `check` returns true (already logged in) and the user is redirected to the route named `dashboard`. It works perfectly, test passes.

Next, I add a new test, to test the "user attempts to log in when nobody's logged in" case. Here's the code for that test:

```
public function test_login_notLoggedIn()
{
    // arrange
    //
    \Sentry::shouldReceive("getUser")
        ->twice()
        ->andReturn(null);

    \Sentry::shouldReceive("check")
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(false);

    // act
    //
    $response = $this->client->request("GET", "/login");

    // assert
    //
    $h2 = $response->filter("h2");

    $this->assertEquals("Please sign in", $h2->text());
}
```

When I run this test, the first test passes but I get a `NotFoundHttpException` in the second test method.

There are a couple of strange things about this problem:

1. if I comment out the first test method (`test_login_alreadyLoggedIn`), the second test passes.
2. if I reverse the order of the two test methods, `test_login_notLoggedIn` passes and `test_login_alreadyLoggedIn` fails (ie. the first method in the class passes and the second fails).

This looks to me like some sort of configuration issue - after the first test (which passes), something is messed up and it cannot make the request in the second test - but I'm at a loss. I've gone over the book several times and google but can't find any reference to any configuration that I'm missing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who may run into this problem in the future...

This was caused by problems with my `routes.php` file. In particular, I organized by routes into a set of files:

1. `accounts.php` - contains routes related to "account" functions
2. `admin.php` - contains routes related to "admin" functions
3. etc...

These files were then included in my `routes.php` file with `require_once`. This works fine for my application, but for some reason, the routes were not loaded properly during testing. The solution is to move my routes back to the `routes.php` file until I can find a better way to organize them.

Comment: Thanks, just spent 20 mins debugging the same issue! Changing require_once() to require() in routes.php fixes the testing issue, and I've noticed no other side effects so far.

Comment: Why is it an issue though? Can someone explain the logic behind that?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by replacing your `require_once()` to `require()`